# dialog (shell script program) but for C/C++ programs

Tags: c++, dialog, console, terminal

I'm looking for a library or something usable from C/C++ (cross-platform if possible) that does something similar to the program "dialog", which is/was available on most Linux systems. Basically, I would like a simple menu similar to `dialog --menu`, but I don't want to have to write too much code for it. Console-based is fine; does anyone know of such a library?

By the way, does anyone know a good Google shortcut to search for the program "dialog" as opposed to GUI dialog boxes (e.g. "golang" for the Go programming language)? I can't get "dialog" to produce useful results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yad](http://code.google.com/p/yad/) is yet another dialog.

[Google this](http://bit.ly/MaYjID).

Comment: Didn't know about yad! Do you know of one that is callable/usable from non-shell scripts, e.g. a C++ program? I know I can just exec() it but I'd prefer an actual header file and library...

Comment: It's open-source, so you could call the same functions the command-line parser does. If however you want to create cross-platform dialogs programmatically, then GTK, Wx or Qt are more suited for that.

Answer (score 2):

`dialog` actually comes with a library. It is mentioned in the manual page.

If you use the following, it will show you the info on how to use that library. It is a static library and it has a `dialog.h` file:

```
man 3 dialog
```

The Ubuntu manual page includes an example:

```
#include <dialog.h>

int main(void)
{
    int status;
    init_dialog(stdin, stdout);
    status = dialog_yesno(
                 "Hello, in dialog-format",
                 "Hello World!",
                 0, 0);
    end_dialog();
    return status;
}
```

And to link, you have to specify the `dialog` and `ncurses` libraries as in:

```
g++ ... -ldialog -lncurses my-test.cpp -o my-test ...
```

Here is a list of the widgets:

```
extern int dialog_buildlist(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*list_height*/, int /*item_no*/, char ** /*items*/, int /*order_mode*/);
extern int dialog_calendar(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*subtitle*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*day*/, int /*month*/, int /*year*/);
extern int dialog_checklist(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*list_height*/, int /*item_no*/, char ** /*items*/, int /*flag*/);
extern int dialog_dselect(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*path*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/);
extern int dialog_editbox(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*file*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/);
extern int dialog_form(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*form_height*/, int /*item_no*/, char ** /*items*/);
extern int dialog_fselect(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*path*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/);
extern int dialog_gauge(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*percent*/);
extern int dialog_helpfile(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*file*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/);
extern int dialog_inputbox(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, const char * /*init*/, const int /*password*/);
extern int dialog_menu(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*menu_height*/, int /*item_no*/, char ** /*items*/);
extern int dialog_mixedform(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*form_height*/, int /*item_no*/, char ** /*items*/);
extern int dialog_mixedgauge(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*percent*/, int /*item_no*/, char ** /*items*/);
extern int dialog_msgbox(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*pauseopt*/);
extern int dialog_pause(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*seconds*/);
extern int dialog_prgbox(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, const char * /*command*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*pauseopt*/);
extern int dialog_progressbox(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/);
extern int dialog_rangebox(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*file*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*min_value*/, int /*max_value*/, int /*default_value*/);
extern int dialog_tailbox(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*file*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*bg_task*/);
extern int dialog_textbox(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*file*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/);
extern int dialog_timebox(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*subtitle*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*hour*/, int /*minute*/, int /*second*/);
extern int dialog_treeview(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*subtitle*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*list_height*/, int /*item_no*/, char ** /*items*/, int /*flag*/);
extern int dialog_yesno(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/);
```

As we can see, one of the widgets is `dialog_menu()`.

Here is also a few other definitions including a `dlg_menu()`:

```
extern int dlg_checklist(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*list_height*/, int /*item_no*/, DIALOG_LISTITEM * /*items*/, const char * /*states*/, int /*flag*/, int * /*current_item*/);
extern int dlg_form(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*form_height*/, int /*item_no*/, DIALOG_FORMITEM * /*items*/, int * /*current_item*/);
extern int dlg_menu(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*menu_height*/, int /*item_no*/, DIALOG_LISTITEM * /*items*/, int * /*current_item*/, DIALOG_INPUTMENU /*rename_menu*/);
extern int dlg_progressbox(const char * /*title*/, const char * /*cprompt*/, int /*height*/, int /*width*/, int /*pauseopt*/, FILE * /* fp */);
```

That manual page gives you a lot of information about all of these functions. So it's worth reading through it.

---

Here is a link to a FreeBSD copy of that specific manual page:

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dialog&sektion=3

---

I also have an example of a [CUI connection](https://github.com/m2osw/eventdispatcher/blob/main/eventdispatcher/cui_connection.cpp) in my [`eventdispatcher` project](https://github.com/m2osw/eventdispatcher). This is one additional step as the `eventdispatcher` library listens for events on CUI file descriptor allowing you to write applications that seamlessly handle many connections such as network sockets, directory changes, Unix signal, etc. without the need for multi-threading. Note that `ncurses` is not really usable with multiple threads anyway.

Comment: I am trying to use this in C++ but I can't find any example of how to use it. Perhaps you can point me in the right direction. I have dialog installed and I can use it in Bash, but wish to use it in C++

Comment: I added the example. The manual page shows how to compile/link with the library. It's a static version so it's pretty easy. The library comes with a tool that gives you the flags and libraries (probably using `pkg-config`). It should work in C and C++. From what I can see there is an `extern "C"` in the header so you can include it as is  from C++.

Comment: I tried to run the snippet of code you have above. I am including dialog.h but when I run it I get undefined reference to 'init_dialog' so I think I am missing something, somewhere. I am using the gcc compiler. Is there some kind of switch I should be adding like -dialog or something?

Comment: No, no special flags. It's directly in `/usr/include`, so it should work as is. I added the `#include ...` just in case you did not put that in you `.cpp` file.

Comment: Your answer does not mention the linking (**`-ldialog -lcurses`**).

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry, I misunderstood the _"undefined reference"_ error. Yes. You have to specify the libraries to link against. I use `cmake` so that's a `find_package()` and `target_link_libraries()` so I rarely deal with the actual command line now a day.

Comment: Great stuff man!!!

Answer (score 0):

The *dialog* itself is based on [curses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), which is a freely distributed [GNU project](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

P.S. I ususally use "dialog bash" as key words for Google searches.

Comment: It also offers its own library (See my answer) which is a layer above `ncurses`. I think that OP did not want to redesign the whole `dialog` functionality (good idea!)